# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import while using Nuxt 2.0 build.transpile

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, nuxt.js, babel-loader

I'm using Nuxt@2 `build.transpile` option (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#transpile):

**nuxt.config.js**

```
build: {
  transpile: [
    '@namespace/node-module-name/file.js'
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately I still get the error while build:

```
✖ error /Users/me/project/node_modules/@namespace/node-module-name/file.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import createAPI from '@namespace/api';
 ^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Does nuxt babel configuration is capable of replacing `import`s with umd, commonjs, etc.?

Comment: Can you create a reproduction on codesandbox or github repo please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
import createAPI from '@namespace/api'
```

please try something like:

```
const createAPI = require('@namespace/api')
```